# Modify the value where the C++ pointer is poiting to

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a function which receives a pointer, I'd like to modify the value of where the pointer is poiting to.

```
// How a 'State' looks like 
State s = std::array<std::array<Player,7>,6>;

// I'm receiving a pointer to the state
void Set(State *s, int col, int row, Player player) 
{
    // Modify the state (s)
    s[row][col] = player; // not working
    *s[row][col] = player; // not working
    s->[row][col] = player; // compile error
}
```

How to correctly modify the value (Player) using a pointer?

Comment: Why are you passing by pointer?  Pass it by reference and you can use it like you would normally.

Comment: `(*s)[...][...]`